# How to check if a file exist, delete content or create it

Tags: c

i would like to check if a file exist, delete content if it exists or create it if not.

I have tried :

```
open("screenshot.bmp", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC);
```

But the file don't update if it already exists, if it doesn't the file is created correctly.

```
if ((fd = open("screenshot.bmp", O_CREAT, S_IRWXU)) > -1)
    return (-1);
close (fd);
if ((fd = open("screenshot.bmp", O_TRUNC)) > -1)
    return (-1);
```

But the file looks corrupted/empty after that (it should be filled by the rest of my code)

I also tried other ways.

Thanks for help !

Comment: Both of these look okay to me, except that you forgot to pass S_IRWXU in the first one.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "check if a file exist." What will you do if it *does* exist? If you destroy it then why do you care if it exists?

Comment: If the file exist : i empty it because i will write the new content in it later.
If not : i create it and fill it later

Comment: If it gets truncated correctly, and doesn't get filled, then maybe you should fix the part of your code that's supposed to fill it, instead of the part that's supposed to truncate it?

Comment: The part that fill it works when i delete the file manually, the file gets created and fill
But when the file already exists it looks like O_TRUNC don't do anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `FILE *fd = fopen("screenshot.bmp", "w");`

Accorsing to [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm):

> FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode)

> "w"
>
> Creates an empty file for writing. If a file with the same name already exists, its content is erased and the file is considered as a new empty file.

Update:
OP says `fopen(...)` isn't allowed, but...

According to [the docs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/open.html) you can achieve the same result as the `fopen(...)` call using:

`open (filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, mode)`

For example (from the docs):

> The following example opens the file /tmp/file, either by creating it (if it does not already exist), or by truncating its length to 0 (if it does exist). In the former case, if the call creates a new file, the access permission bits in the file mode of the file are set to permit reading and writing by the owner, and to permit reading only by group members and others.
>
> If the call to open() is successful, the file is opened for writing.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
...
int fd;
mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;
char *filename = "/tmp/file";
...
fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, mode);
...
```

Comment: So that won't check if the file already exists. It will destroy it.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use fopen, do you know if there is the same things for open ?

Comment: @WeatherVane That's what the asker wants though.

Comment: @user253751 it is unclear what OP wants. Whether to open an exisiting file, or create a new one.

Comment: @WeatherVane "if it exists, delete content, or create it"

Comment: Update: I added another option since OP said `fopen(...)` isn't allowed. You can see my changes